How to determine rise and fall times of MOSFET
Rise and fall times of a PWM switching MOSFET must be paid attention because too slow switching times will decrease the efficiency and too fast will cause ringing. I want to know how to choose a rise and fall times on design stage.
It is said that in an optimum design the gate drive speed at turn-on is matched to the diode switching characteristic. That means if I have a 3.7ns Trr diode, I can choose rise time as 10ns. Even lower.
For the fall time there seems to be no limit besides ringing so maybe I can choose it as 10ns as well.
In my case, there is atmega328p running with 16 MHz oscillator controlling a MOSFET via a gate driver and I don't want the ringing MOSFET to interfere with it. Should I choose the edge speed so fast that it is much greater than the oscillator frequency (for 10ns it is 1/10ns = 100MHz which is much greater than 16MHz) Or should I choose it much slower such as 500ns. If I choose rise or fall time as 60ns then the edge will be 16.7Mhz which is close to the oscillator, is that bad?
Would you guide me through rise and fall times to obtain best efficiency without interference. I will choose the driver and gate resistors accordingly.
VDS = 24V
f_pwm = 1kHz
VGS = 12V
ID = 4A

Proposed are mostly unrelated parameters.  The MCU in particular bears no relation at all; any interference it is subject to, is the fault of poor layout, filtering and interconnection.
Note that, if nothing else, every sub-circuit can be sealed inside a metal box, with filtering applied to signals where they pass through that box, sealing any interference within.  That is, shielding and filtering, at the most fundamental, should be approached topologically: there is a barrier, beyond which, a noisy sub-circuit cannot transmit, and some signals that pass that barrier subject to strict scrutiny and careful design.
A topological approach limits design scope, making filtering and control of signal quality a tractable problem.  We could, in principle, consider an open circuit, a mess of spaghetti, but the interactions are strongly coupled between all connections and design is intractable even for fairly small circuits.
Filtering, of course, is subject to signal bandwidth requirements, and we would generally want at least several MHz bandwidth for something like a gate drive signal going to a switching circuit, and at least some 100s kHz for the current sense signal coming back from a switching circuit (assuming we're using the objectively best control scheme that is current-mode control).  For higher-bandwidth signals, we modify the requirement to optimize signal quality: keep the signal near the box's shielding surface (inside and out), and avoid routing near heavy switching currents.  Use differential techniques if necessary, so that the signal is accompanied by a reference, both subject to the same nearby fields, the same connecting impedances, the voltages of which are canceled out at the endpoint by suitable design (e.g. diff amp).
For a switching circuit, we can apply the signal quality principle directly.  Consider the basic buck or boost circuit, consisting of two switches in a half-bridge configuration: there exists some physical distance between them, and thus a length scale for connecting traces/pours.
In a circuit, length means inductance.
More exactly, length means transmission lines, which we can generally take the low-frequency approximation of in switching circuits, and so we get series inductance and shunt capacitance in proportion to the impedance and length of that transmission line.
Any conductive geometry can be a transmission line, or more specifically, between any adjacent pairs of conductors can be.  Most often these are traces/pours on a PCB, with respect to ground plane, or each other, and component leads with respect to each other within a component, or sometimes between neighboring components.
Thus we enhance the circuit like so:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With waveforms like so:

Observe that, for each switching event (commutation), we have one device turning off, deadtime, then the other device turning on.  In that moment, V(SW) may be high or low.
When V(SW) is high and M2 turns on, or low and M1 turns on, it is referred to as hard switching, and the full switching loss associated with Coss1 + Coss2 is dissipated.
During commutation, I(LSW) may be high or low, so that V(SW)'s capacitance is pushed around by that current, during the dead time.  When this occurs in a smooth fashion, it is referred to as ZVS (zero-voltage switching): notice Coss1/2 holds V(SW) near zero while the first transistor turns off, the voltage swings until the body diode conducts, and then the second transistor turns on, its Vds already being near zero.
Here, we have ZVS at M1 turn-off and M2 turn-on.
Conversely, if I(LSW) is low, or opposite the direction required for ZVS on a given switching event, we will have hard switching, or, at best, ZCS (zero current switching).  Here, we have I(LSW) low, V(SW) low, and M1 turning on, for a hard-switched event.  (M2 turn-off is also ZVS, so that's three out of four total events: not bad, considering.)  Note that V(SW) has considerable ringing and overshoot, and I(M1) also shows significant peak current at the same time.  This ringing is due to Coss2 + LS1 + LS2 + LS3, and 500pF + 30nH is a resonant frequency of 41MHz and characteristic impedance of 7.7Ω.  The ~10ns gate drive edges here are comparable to the quarter-cycle period of this ringing, so the ringing is significant and cannot be ignored in design.
These values chosen, by the way, are typical of the IRF530 shown.  Roughly speaking, component lead length, trace length, etc. contribute between 0.5-1 nH per mm of length.  The TO-220 package is commonly attributed as 7.5nH in the D-S path, and another 2.5nH between parts suggests they are adjacent on a PCB, and to CBYP (which, as shown, might be an electrolytic capacitor).
Exercise for the student:
Draw the equivalent circuits, at instant of turn-on, or turn-off, for the various cases: I(LSW) high or low, V(SW) high or low, M1 or M2 turning on or off.
Transform M's to switches, and reduce the circuit for any switches not changing state.  Observe which Coss(1/2) are in circuit, or shorted out.  Observe LS1+LS2+LS3 is always present, as the switching loop inductance.  Also observe that LSW is basically a CCS during the switching event.
At last, we can address the question posed at the top:

How to determine rise and fall times of MOSFET?

We generally want to stay slower than the loop (LS + Coss) resonant period.  This depends on component choice and layout/routing, so is a layout-dependent parameter.  Typically, some 10s of ns can be achieved, but it depends on the components, and construction technique.  Transistors on solderless breadboard with carelessly long fly leads, will incur 100s of nH between them, and switching at 100s of ns will be problematic; not to mention the mutual inductance between every loop in the circuit, sure to carry interference right back to your Arduino or whatever.  With trimmed jumpers and careful layout, high 10s of ns is feasible on the breadboard, with ~100s of mV or less of common mode or conducted/induced ground noise.  For more than a few amperes of load current, and certainly into the low 10s of ns switching rate, I would strongly encourage a planar construction method, whether Manhattan style over copper-clad, or a printed circuit board as such, designed with signals always above or below a solid ground plane.
We generally control switching speed by choice of gate driver, series gate resistance, and, more and more often these days as nonlinear capacitances are optimized so well, we may further need to consider negative feedback, whether in terms of current (e.g. common source inductance, ferrite bead) or voltage (shunt feedback from drain to gate, e.g. an R+C of very modest values; for the above simulation, try 10R series gate plus 100R + 22pF D-G).
Finally, note that the switching edge rates, and any ringing, determine the bandwidth of the shielding and filtering solution that we must employ to isolate this noisy section from surrounding circuitry.  For edges of 10ns, a bandwidth of ~50MHz leads to a fairly easy-to-implement solution.  Mind that I'm using "bandwidth" in a negative sense here: the range over which the shield/filter is effective -- the stopband.
Modern Si switches regularly emit harmonics into the 200MHz range, let alone SiC and GaN devices which can go much further (1GHz+); their shielding and filtering solutions are much more demanding!

Very Informative, still trying to comprehend all. Giving more detail, I only have single MOSFET dimming a LED strip. So probably no ZVS or ZCS. I'm planning to use UCC27516 to charge 17nC input capacitor which seems overkill but that's the cheapest driver oddly. Reconsidering switching times, resonant period calculation is: Coss = 326pF as in datasheet and Lstray is maybe 20nH who knows, considering the very small packages: gate driver(WSON) gate resistors(0402) MOSFET(PG-TDSON-8). Tresonant = 1/(2pisqrt(Lstray*Coss)) = 16ns and I've chosen 30ns for tr and tf with safety.

I will place the MOSFET and driver very close. Should I put MCU as close to the driver? Or should it be far away from noisy switch node? I was planning to use 2 layer board full ground plane at the bottom and ground pour on top. Should I consider 4 layer just to get ground plane closer to the switch node?

LED strip; will this be bucking (onboard filter) or switching directly?  It's generally not a good idea to transmit switching edges over wiring.  Filtering doesn't need to be complete (smoothed DC output), but it should at least be provided to increase switching times, or a slow switching speed used (and low Fsw). LEDs pulsating at some kHz is generally acceptable for visual purposes, and switching edges of ~1us fairly safe for EMC purposes.

I first thought of analog dimming but it has drawbacks. The length of the strip is limited by current sense resistors, low dimming is nonlinear and complex circuit. All that is for what? How much efficiency difference is there between PWM and analog dimming? I hope it is really low. Please consider V_LED=VDS=24V, no bucking. Also, I will put a flyback diode between LED- node and 24V+ node, this should eliminate any inductive disturbance of LED at turn-off. The switching edges are still there as you said so should I consider RCD snubber or 1us rise and fall times which is quite long?

One thing I realize is that analog dimming doesn't stop transmitting of fast voltage changes over wires because in analog dimming there is only an inductor between LED- terminal and drain, the inductor won't stop the voltage change at the LED- wire, it only delays current. The edges will still cause EMI. But this is the nature of current source, what else could be done?? (I know that PWM isn't a current source but at least dimming is linear)

Not sure what you mean by "analog dimming". It brings to my mind, a voltage- (or PWM-)controlled current sink, which would have a question of efficiency, and CRI at low output if these are white LEDs. But it's not very complex, and how would it have fast voltage changes? In any case, it seems like we're done with this question; if you have further questions, you may consider asking new ones on such topics. Cheers!

Is using linear dimming function of this IC more efficient: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/HV9910C-Data-Sheet-DS20005323.pdf I didn't use any IC because I didn't need to change voltage as my supply and LED are both 24V and PWM dimming didn't seem any worse than linear dimming, does PWM method has drawbacks? On the internet they say PWM is complex but in reality it is even simpler.

PWM is generally an easy and effective way to go for LEDs, yes. There are considerations that need to be made, you can't just slap together any MOSFET and driver; but that's a separate question.

Great news. Though you made me worried about my design, maybe I should thank you for that. The separate question I opened regarding diming methods comparison is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/710880/pwm-led-dimming-circuit-design-recommendations-and-comparison-against-linear-dim
